# Terminal and character written by cat

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I am trying to understand a little bit better what those kind of symbols come from and what is their meaning. If I run cat

```
xxx@xxx-debian:~$ cat
^[[A^[[A
```

In that case I was typing Up arrow.

I think that the symbols typed has something to do with the terminal type configured, where can I get some info more about it ?
Is there a table which specifies the mapping between what is typed and what it is printed on the screen ?

Basically what I would like to do is to map what it comes from the tmux when I type Ctrl-UP, which is 
^[[A

in my .vimrc file, how can I specifically do that ?
Anyway my question is much more general and as you could have understood I am a bit confused about all this.

Comment: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` has not written any characters here. It will not get any characters, and will not produce any, until you press Enter. This is what your terminal sends to the program connected to it.

The mapping between special keys and byte sequences they produce is specific to each terminal type and hardwired into it. There is a database on your computer that summarizes this information, and much more, for many types of terminals. This database is called "the terminfo database". You can read about it by typing `man 5 terminfo` command in your shell.

Many programs such as `vi` and `bash` that read and understand arrow keys and other special keys consult this database. Not all programs do (`cat` for example does not). There are libraries such as `ncurses` that encapsulate the minute details of all this, so that you can use high-level concepts such as "Up key" instead of interpreting sequences like `^[[A`.

Comment: How can I get my terminal type ? echo $TERM ? In my case for example is screen-256color, how could I get more info about the byte sequences ?

Comment: (1) yes `echo $TERM`. (2) study output of `infocmp`, look at `kcuu1` and `cuu1` (why these? look them up in `man 5 terminfo`), just bear in mind that `kcuu1` and siblings are not necessarily correct in all terminal modes and `cuu1` et al need to be used instead (I don't know exactly why or when this is the case).

Answer (score 0):

It is the escape sequence generated

`^[` ESC character and `[` and `A` helps in denote its `UP Arrow` key.

So as a combination `^[[A` OS understands the user has pressed `UP Arrow` key.